# How do I get all values of a foreach into a PHP variable?

Tags: php

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
  $var = $test['somekey'];
}
echo $var;
```

How do I get all values of a foreach into a php variable? It seems to be picking up only the last variable.

Comment: "Get into" how exactly? Put them into an array? `array_column`.

Comment: Really unclear. Could be implode, or $test my be what you're after. Can you explain more? (Or just "echo" stuff out to see what's what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're overwriting $var on each iteration.  with a dot as follows, this will append instead of overwrite.
`$var .= $test['somekey'];`

Comment: yes. that's it. thanks. I had forgotton

Comment: you should then mark the answer as correct

Comment: how do I do a conditional to check last item in array?

Comment: you could get the array size and compare to an iterative counter. `$count = count($tests); $i = 0; foreach ($tests as $test) { $i++; if ($i == $count) { # last element }`

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for depends on what you wish to do.
If you wish for an array, use:

```
$var = array();
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $var[] = $test['somekey'];
}
print_r($var);
```

or if you have PHP version >= 5.5.0 you can use:

```
$var = array_column($tests, $test);
```

If you wish for a string, use:

```
$var = "";
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $var .= $test['somekey'];
}
print_r($var);
```

If you wish for a number, use:

```
$var = 0;
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $var += $test['somekey'];
}
print_r($var);
```

You could also use any of the [Assignment Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) instead of the `+=` to do whatever you wanted!

Comment: A simple answer that saved my day. Thanks!! thats awesome that array [] brackets is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$data = array() ;
foreach ($tests as $test) {
  $data[] = $test['somekey'];
}

echo implode(" ; ", $data) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$var = array_map(function ($v) {
    return $v['somekey'];
}, $tests);

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

> it seems to be picking up the last variable only

That's because `$var` is a variable, not an array. You're just overriding the same variable multiple times: the only value which will remain is the last one.

Convert `$var` to an array in your code.

```
$var = new array();
```

then use something like `array_push` to add the value in the array

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
  array_push($var, $test['somekey']);
}
```

finally, you may want to print out the value. `echo` is not the ideal way to print out an array. I'd recommend using [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) enclosed in `<pre>` tags.

```
echo ("<pre>");
var_dump($var);
echo ("</pre>");
```